# Python - Reformat a JSON API response from Binance

Tags: python, json, api

So, according to Python-Binance's documentation, the thing I am getting back is a dictionary JSON response. When I get the response it looks like this:

```
{'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'price': '37256.90000000'}
```

What I want to do is take that and reformat it so it looks like this:

```
'$BTC @ 37256.900'
```

Basically removing the braces and all the other garbage that isn't needed.

The code I was using from the Binance API with [Python-Binance](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html#binance.client.Client.get_all_tickers) and the way I was printing it:

```
price = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol="BTCUSDT")

from crypto_tracker import price
print(price)
```

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a great library called [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to help you take a json string and create a python dict from it.

From your example I have created the following code:

```
import json

## Given example string
json_string = '{"symbol": "BTCUSDT", "price": "37256.90000000"}'

## Create a python dict from json string using json library json.loads
json_dict = json.loads(json_string)

## What the new python dict looks like:
## json_dict = {'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'price': '37256.90000000'}

## Print your expected output
print(f'$BTC @ {json_dict["price"]}')
```

**Print Output:**

```
$BTC @ 37256.90000000
```

Using the python "json" library will automatically convert the json string to a python dict which you can then use any way you like (i.e. automatically removing all the extra "braces and ... other garbage that isn't needed.").

**Edit:**

Per more back and forth in comments I took a look at the Binance API. The API endpoint your using is:

```
GET /api/v3/ticker/price
```

To get information from this you would need to make an HTTP request to:

```
https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price
```

Here is example working code:

```
import requests
import json

## Send a GET request to binance api
## Since this is a get request no apikey / secret is needed
response = requests.get("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT")

## Print the text from the get request
## Output: {"symbol":"BTCUSDT","price":"37211.17000000"}
print(response.text)

## Response.text is a string so we can use json.loads on it
ticket = json.loads(response.text)

## Now that ticket is a python dict of the json string
## response from binance we can print what you want
print(f'$BTC @ {ticket["price"]}')

## Output: $BTC @ 37221.87000000
```

Comment: That's close to what I'm looking for. I probably should have mentioned that the 

`price = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol="BTCUSDT")`

part of my code is in a different file called crypto_price.py. How would I go about taking that live data from there to do the same thing? I think it would have to be converted from a JSON to a string first for your way to work.

Comment: @scs That depends on how you get your live data. Python has no native way to handle a json string without converting it to a dict (or handling the parsing yourself). Most times whatever api you are calling from just straight up gives you a json string in the http response. But to be sure you would have to share your code and what it returns.

Comment: This is the error I get: "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict" And the code: `if message.content.startswith('!crypto'): #crypto
    json_string = {"price" : price}
    json_dict = json.loads(json_string)
    print(f'$BTC @ {json_dict["price"]}')`

The data is called when I put in the !crypto command. It's not through a URL, it's through an API key/Secret key on Binance.

Comment: @scs You need to encapsulate the json with a string. `json_string = '{"price" : price}'` not just `json_string = {"price" : price}`. Are you using some library that binance created that doesn't uses like sockets or something? Because from what I can see binance uses a rest api which would require http requests. If you are making http requests with your api key/secret then the response would be your json string. That text string is your json string which can be directly input into json.loads(). If this doesn't help I would have to see how you are getting the data further.

Comment: @scs I updated my answer with a working example of exactly what you want to do. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: I tried it with encapsulation but when I do that I get an error for 'from crypto_tracker import price' saying it's unused. The issue with put that string into the json_string is that it always prints that string and not the updated price. I'm just using `from Binance.client import Client` with the two API keys given, both of which are in a .py file. I'm then using python-discord which I hyperlinked in the original post.